# Insert multiple lines in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, performance

Performance related:

Is it better to make 1000 queries to insert 1000 rows:

```
    for($i=1;$i<=1000;++$i){
         $query = 'insert into table1 (First,Last) values ("Fred","Smith")';
         mysql_query($query);
    }
```

Or to create a query using PHP (by concatenating values in a for loop) like this:

```
   $query = ' insert into table1 (First,Last) values ("Fred","Smith"),
      ("John","Smith"),
      ...
      ("Michael","Smith"),
      ("Robert","Smith")';
   mysql_query($query);
```

Given that there may be lots of values I chose to insert 10 at a time. I don't know if that's ok, what's the best practice in this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The second is better. Connecting to the database is expensive.

Another way to say it, what's faster? Making 1,000 trips to drop off 1,000 boxes or one trip to drop off 1,000 boxes?

Comment: But what if the truck is not large enough to fit all those boxes? :) (query size limit? )

Comment: @Cristy Then split it into the minimum number of trips containing the maximum number of boxes each. Still _way_ faster than 1000 trips.

Answer (score 3):

This question is, I suppose, answered well enough at the [official site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html):

> If you are inserting many rows from the same client at the same time,
>   use INSERT statements with multiple VALUES lists to insert several
>   rows at a time. This is considerably faster (many times faster in some
>   cases) than using separate single-row INSERT statements.

I'd suggesting the whole page, though, as it lists several strategies for optimizing multi-inserts (for different types of engines). Yet at the very end it mentions that...

> INSERT is still much slower for loading data than LOAD DATA INFILE,
>   even when using the strategies just outlined.

... and that's quite true: if you need some huge (but static) set of data to be loaded into DB, use [**LOAD DATA INFILE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html) statement instead.

Answer (score 0):

the second is better one and you have much control over it , the first u dont have much control about to insert different values

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, cost for batch processing is less than one by one processing. its all about cost over-head, here it's a resource in terms of performance.